# Required attribute does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I tried `required` attribute of `input` tag in HTML. When user inputs empty value, browser should pop up a warning `Please fills out this field`.

It works fine in Chrome browser, but when I use Firefox (version 53.0), the pop up seems like immediately disappear. Here is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" required />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do you know how to fix it? And if can't be fix, can you explain why Firefox doing it?

Update 1: It works on Firefox on Windows. But it still doesn't work on Firefox on Ubuntu (16.04).

Comment: try required ="required "

Comment: It seems working to me (Firefox 53). However, please notice that Firefox just shows a red halo (implemented with `box-shadow`), instead of the popup shown by Chrome and Opera. It may be the case that you have overridden that `box-shadow` in your stylesheet.

Comment: works fine for me too.

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani `required` and `required="required"` are functionally identical in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I have your code work successfully in Firefox (53.0.2) but could you please try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="somename" required>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I made two changes:

- In HTML, the  tag has no end tag but in XHTML.
- Add name attribute because of some possible dependencies.

Comment: Why you think adding name attribute should change behavior of `required`?

Comment: @Justinas 
I thought that maybe this case not about `required` itself. So I made two changes:
1) In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag but in XHTML.
2) Add name attribute because of some possible dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. It still doesn't work though. I think the problem belongs to the browser.